# Count words in a given String

Tags: java, string

I have two approach to determine number of words in String, But the result is `1` forever!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter your String:");
    String string = in.next();
    System.out.println("Number of Words are:" + countWords(string));
    System.out.println("Number of Words are:" + countWords2(string));

}

public static int countWords(String str) {
    String[] splited2 = str.split(" ");
    return splited2.length;

}

public static int countWords2(String str) {
    String trimed = str.trim();
    return trimed.split("\\s+").length;
}
```

Why?

Comment: What's your input for this method? I tried it and it works for me

Comment: Whats your input string?

Comment: Add some input strings along with the expected and the given result.

Comment: @pogopaule for example : `hello world hello world` and it says `1` !

Comment: Do you think the given information in your question is enough to answer it. You have not told us what is `in`. Where is `next()` method. Always add complete information to your question. Best way is to re-read the question when you're done typing, and see if you have given enough information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Scanner#next()` method, which is what I assume you are using, reads the next token, and by default it doesn't consider whitespaces as a part of token. So, it really reads the input till it finds the first whitespace.

So, your input contains just a single word, and hence the result. Try using `Scanner#nextLine()` method, and you will get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Replace in.next() by scanner.nextLine() because next() will give you the next token not all the line

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a sentence:");
String sentence = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Number of Words are:" + countWords(sentence));
```

Or you can use [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) as it is faster in reading whole line

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String sentence = br.readLine();
System.out.println("Number of Words are:" + countWords(sentence));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest building a function like this:

```
public static int getWordCount(String string){

    int counter = 0;

    boolean wordFound = false;
    int endOfLineIndex = s.length() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < endOfLineIndex; i++) {

        if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) == true)) {
            wordFound = true;
        } else if (Character.isLetter(string.charAt(i)) == false && wordFound == true) {
            counter++;
            wordFound = false;
        } else if (Character.isLetter(string.charAt(i))) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Hope I helped!